# Finding Unique Image name from Image column using Pyspark or SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data set which looks like this :

```
key|StateName_13|lon|lat|col5_13|col6_13|col7_13|ImageName|elevation_13|Counter_13
P00005K9XESU|FL|-80.854196|26.712385|128402000128038||183.30198669433594|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img|3.7742109298706055|1
P00005KC31Y7|FL|-80.854196|26.712385|128402000128038||174.34959411621094|USGS_NED_13_n27w082_IMG.img|3.553356885910034|1
P00005KC320M|FL|-80.846966|26.713182|128402000100953||520.3673706054688|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img|2.2236201763153076|1
P00005KC320M|FL|-80.84617434521485|26.713200344482424|128402000100953||520.3673706054688|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img|2.7960102558135986|2
P00005KC320M|FL|-80.84538|26.713219|128402000100953||520.3673706054688|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img|1.7564013004302979|3
P00005KC31Y6|FL|-80.854155|26.712083|128402000128038||169.80172729492188|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img|3.2237753868103027|1
P00005KATEL2|FL|-80.861664|26.703649|128402000122910||38.789894104003906|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img|3.235154628753662|1
```

In this dataset, I want to find the duplicate lon,lat and want the name of images corresponding to those lon and lat.

Output should look like this:

```
lon|lat|ImageName
-80.854196|26.712385|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img,USGS_NED_13_n27w082_IMG.img
```

Since the row 1 and 2 have similar lon and lat values but different image name.
Any pyspark code or sql query works.

Comment: Try `df = df.groupby(['lon','lat']).agg(F.collect_set('ImageName'))`?

Comment: agg(F.collect_set ---> what does F indicates here.

Comment: import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Comment: You really should add your own code attempt to the question. SO is not (supposed to be) a code writing service.

Comment: Have scribbled my code after reporting the question.
Find my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @giser_yugang comment, we can do something like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.groupby(
    'lon',
    'lat'
).agg(
    F.collect_set('ImageName').alias("ImageNames")
).where(
    F.size("ImageNames")>1
)

df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|lon       |lat      |ImageNames                                                |
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|-80.854196|26.712385|[USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img, USGS_NED_13_n27w082_IMG.img]|
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you need to write it in a csv, as the format does not support `ArrayType`, then you can use [`concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws)

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "ImageNames",
    F.concat_ws(
        ", "
        "ImageNames"
    )
)

df.show()
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+ 
|lon       |lat      |ImageNames                                              |
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|-80.854196|26.712385|USGS_NED_13_n27w081_IMG.img, USGS_NED_13_n27w082_IMG.img|
+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have tried :
dup_df = data.groupBy('lon_13','lat_13').agg(collect_list("ImageName_13").alias("ImageName_13")).where(size("ImageName_13")>1)

Comment: @SahilNagpal which is the same, isn't it ?

Comment: the problem I am facing is that I am not able to write my data frame into a csv or text because data frame does not support set or list(Array) data type to csv or text.

Comment: I am running this :

dup_df = data.groupBy('lon_13','lat_13').agg(collect_set("ImageName_13").alias("ImageName_13")).where(size("ImageName_13")>1)
newdup = dup_df.withColumn("ImageName_13",concat_ws(", ""ImageName_13"))
newdup.show(20,False)

I am having an empty image column

Comment: join_udf = udf(lambda x: ",".join(x))
df.withColumn("test_123", join_udf(col("test_123"))).show()

this is what I have tried

Comment: @SahilNagpal udf impacts your performances. Better use builtin functions.